# How to access the Playlists of sub-accounts from a parent YouTube Account OR maintain authorization of a sub-account?

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

Using the YouTube Javascript API to login, the user is given the choice of which account to select (when there are multiple linked YouTube accounts). The Playlists only seem to be accessible for whichever account is chosen. (Other lists like Uploaded Videos are available from either for some reason.)

This wouldn't be a problem if the sub-accounts would stay logged in, but they seem to interact differently with the refresh tokens and are asked for permission at every request.

I'm using the test cases provided by Google: https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client

You can recreate the problem (on one of the examples) by authorizing a sub-account and refreshing the page to see that it will request permission again. If you use the parent account it will not.

If there isn't a way to keep the sub-account authorized, another solution would be to access the playlists from the parent account, but they don't show up using the "mine" parameter and there doesn't seem to be a way to get the channel id of a sub-account from the parent account.

Answer (score 1):

`onBehalfOfContentOwner` optional parameter is given out in [Videos: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#parameters) which you can use. It indicates that:

> The request's authorization credentials identify a YouTube CMS user who is acting on behalf of the content owner specified in the parameter value. This parameter is intended for YouTube content partners that own and manage many different YouTube channels. It allows content owners to authenticate once and get access to all their video and channel data, without having to provide authentication credentials for each individual channel. The CMS account that the user authenticates with must be linked to the specified YouTube content owner.

Please note that this parameter can only be used in a properly authorized request and is intended exclusively for YouTube content partners.

Comment: Thank you. This does seem to be what I'm looking for, but the documentation notes that "This parameter is intended exclusively for YouTube content partners." I don't have any content. I'm simply trying to display the content of the user who is logged in. I'm having trouble finding a way to access the ID of the user which I would use in this field.